# How to go back to the last screen after accidently click “Ctrl+A, c” when using Screen on Ubuntu

Tags: screen

This happens to me all the time. What I actually want to do is "Ctrl+A, Shift+|". But instead, I accidently hit "Ctrl+A, Shift+C". And it brings me to a new instance of screen.

But there are some output on my last screen which I would like to reference later. Wonder how to get back to it?

Comment: Are you talking about the Screen package?

Comment: Yes, I am talking about it. I usually use it to split my screen in one terminal or detached it at work while running big tests and reattach from my laptop to see the output when I got home.

Comment: Ctrl + a + d would be the shortcut for detach and Ctrl + d to close a screen

Comment: I use Ctrl + a + d command sometimes. But my problem is, if I accidentally hit Ctrl+a+c, how to go back to the screen instance which just gone. That is just a mistake and I want  to go back to the last sceen.

Comment: Ctrl+A, Shift+C does _clear_ the screen while Ctrl+A, C opens a new window. What have you done actually?

Answer (score 0):

You can always use

```
screen -ls
```

to list all opened screens with their PID, and then you can just type

```
screen -r PID
```

to switch into that screen. For more information use

```
man screen
```

Comment: hmm, I think Ctrl+a+c stays in the same PID... It just opens a new instance...